# Google sheets array search

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

I am trying to write a formula where Cells A2:A16 are searched for numerical values and the results are output in cells C2:F2.

Within the data that will populate in A2:A16, there will only be 0-4 occurrences of a numerical value only (as seen below in column A).

For value 1 & 2 it will always be a number between 0-101 and for values 3 & 4 it will always be a number between 102-999. What is the best formula I can write for cells C2:F2 to get the results to populate like they do in yellow below?

[image: Sheet showing A1:F16]

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` like this:

cell C2:

```
=transpose( filter(A2:A, isnumber(A2:A), A2:A <= 101) )
```

...and:

cell E2:

```
=transpose( filter(A2:A, A2:A > 101) )
```

The `isnumber(A2:A)` bit is required to skip empty cells whose value is considered zero and thus below `101`.