# Filter function outputting results differently depending on greater or less than

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I am using a filter function to pull out numbers from a column. I have one function which is grabbing numbers over 101 and it is outputting them perfectly in two vertical cells this formula:

=(filter(J2:J21, J2:J21>=101))

However when I write this same formula for numbers under 101 which is:

=(filter(J2:J21, J2:J21<=101))

it outputs the numbers multiple cells away from each other and the distance matches how far away they were in the original list pulled from.

I find this odd since the only difference is switching the > to a <

Can anyone help me on this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Use an additional condition of `isnumber(J2:J21)`. See the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168050/269219) to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
Please try
`=FILTER(J2:J21, (J2:J21<=101)*(J2:J21>0))`

or `=FILTER(J2:J21, (J2:J21<=101)*(J2:J21<>""))`

*(empty cells are less than 101, right?)*

Comment: That worked!!!  Thank you so much!